# Partial load after button click MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page where I'm showing notes and after clicking a button I want to be able to add a note. The following code is the part how I tried to load the create note action result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
    $('#load-partial'.click(function(){
        $('#partial'.load('/EntityController/CreateNote/');});
    })();    
</script>

<div id="partial"></div>
<button type="button" id="load-partial" />
```

However, clicking the button does not do anything. What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good suggestions from Darin Dimitrov. To go to the next level

> > You need to use url helpers: $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity")');

To make this unobtrusive (and move the java script to a file), you need to use the @URL helper to set an action attribute/value, then harvest the action attribute value in the JavaScript. In my pending DropDownList tutorial I do the following:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("IndexDDL", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id = "CountryStateFormID",
 StateListAction = @Url.Action("StateList") })) {
```

-- then in the JavaScript

```
$('#CountriesID').change(function () {
    var CountryStateFormID = $('#CountryStateFormID');
    $.getJSON(CountryStateFormID.attr('StateListAction') + '/' + $('#CountriesID').val(), function (data) {
```

You should also use IE9/F12 developer tools or Chrome or FF to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

> What goes wrong here?

For starters you have lots of javascript errors in what you have shown. Also are not waiting for the DOM to be ready before subscribing to events like `click`. You just created an anonymous function that you executed immediately without waiting for the DOM to be ready. It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#load-partial').click(function() {
            $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity")');
        });
    });    
</script>

<div id="partial"></div>
<button type="button" id="load-partial" />
```

Other than that there could be like gazillions of things can go wrong here (which unfortunately we cannot rule out from the poor code snippet you provided):

- You forgot to reference jquery
- You referenced jquery after the script you have shown
- You referenced jquery but provided a wrong url
- The controller action that should return the partial doesn't exist
- The controller action that should return the partial throws an exception
- The controller action that should return the partial doesn't throw an exception but it doesn't find the partial view in the searched (by convention) locations
- The controller action that should return the partial doesn't throw an exception and it finds the partial but there is an error in this partial (wrong syntax, null reference exception, ... this list goes to infinity as well)
- You didn't use url helpers when generating the url to the action, so if you deployed this application inside a virtual directory the `/EntityController/CreateNote/` url is probably wrong. You need to use url helpers: `$('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity")');`
- You used `/EntityController` as controller name but according to conventions the Controller suffix is only use when naming your controller classes, but not when referencing an url. So the url should probably be `/entity/createnote` (see previous reason for the correct way to generate urls).
- You have some javascript error in a portion of the page that you didn't show. Use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to debug your scripts and AJAX requests.
- ... this list goes on to infinity

Comment: Thank you for the constructive critisism and the kind pointers on how I can improve my questions in the future.

Comment: >>. You need to use url helpers: $('#partial').load('@Url.Action("CreateNote", "Entity")');